# Table Fixed Header Plugin that retains OnClick

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a table built dynamically with PHP.  The PHP gives each row an on click event that highlights the selected row and display details associated with it in another section of the page.

I wanted this table to be sortable so I started using this:
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

That worked great, it was sortable, selectable, and moderately fast.

I started looking into fixed headers as well and found this:
http://www.tablefixedheader.com/

Sorting and fixed headers.  Awesome.

This works in all the ways I want to but it's unfortunately slow and gets rid of the onClick event I create for each table row.

That's not acceptable, in fact, it fundamentally breaks my application.
Is there a better plugin, a way to prevent this or an easier solution?

I need a sortable table with a fixed header that allows me to add unique onClick events and IDs to each table row.  And I really don't want to write my own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables changed my life.
http://datatables.net/index

The fixed header functionality is an "extra": http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/

Comment: Wow, you win my daily allotment of Internets for the week.  This plugin is incredibly robust.  The documentation is absolutely terrible but I am very impressed not the less.  Thank you.  Now to wade through all the information on that god awful website.

Comment: The Examples pages helped me a lot. And when you're looking at the API stuff, remember to click the "Show Details" link to get actual info.

Comment: Out quick curiosity, is there a good way to prevent the unstyled table from displaying.  It stays ugly for a couple seconds and then the javascript kicks in and fixes it.

Comment: I've never tried to do that. You might try setting its initial display property to none and then toggling it on after calling the DataTable initialization. I don't know if that would mess up the initialization stuff or not.

Comment: I went with table{display:none} and then table.dataTable {display:table;}.  That way, when the table loads, it's not shown and when the class associated with dataTable is loaded, it loads looking just like it should.  Great trick for poorly optimized code :D